# how do I align text to fontawesome icon

Tags: html, font-awesome

i searched through similar questions and still could not find a solution. I have a fontawesome icon that triggers an expanding form.

```
      <div class='create-inventory-form'></div>
              <div class='icon fa fa-pencil' id='form-container'>  
          <!-- <span>Create</span>  I tried this but it only shows on the pop-up form-->
                <span class='icon fa fa-close' id='form-close'></span>
                <div id='form-content'>
                  <div id='form-head'>
                    <h1 class='pre'>Add New Item to Inventory</h1>
                    <p class='pre'>Good choice...</p>
                    <h1 class='post'>Thanks!</h1>
                    <p class='post'>I'll be in touch ASAP</p>
                  </div>
                  <form>
                    <input class='input name' name='user_name' placeholder='Your name please' type='text'>
                    <input class='input email' name='user_email' placeholder='A contact email' type='text'>
                    <select class='input select' name='subject'>
                      <option disabled=''>What shall we talk about?</option>
                      <option selected=''>About a new project</option>
                      <option>About a job opportunity</option>
                      <option>Let's do this over a coffee</option>
                    </select>
                    <textarea class='input message' placeholder='How can I help?'></textarea>
                    <input class='input submit' type='submit' value='Send Message'>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
```

this is what i have with the code above 
[image]

this is what i want to create 
[image]

Comment: can you provide a fiddle. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the respective text to be vertically aligned center with the icon so you have to set a css property Vertical align : middle to your icon class.in your case

```
.fa-pencil:before {
   content: "\f040";
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sikandar_ali_akram/79rtwjg6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.fa{
display:block;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: where will the text be written

Comment: in your css stylesheet

Comment: i mean where and how will the text "center" be implemented

Comment: Please check the fiddle above.I have updated the answer as well

Comment: ok so what i was asking is how do i add the text "center" that will be inline with the camera icon

Comment: You can use inline css for that.But this would be a better approach.